# CephFS: mount fails with "can't read superblock"

Tags: mount, ceph

I have set up Ceph Jewel on 3 nodes equipped with Ubuntu Server 14.04.

```
ceph -v
ceph version 10.2.1 (3a66dd4f30852819c1bdaa8ec23c795d4ad77269)
```

The cluster is up and running:

```
ceph -s
cluster cb3537cf-05a0-4411-840d-ab5b8d855579
 health HEALTH_OK
 monmap e3: 3 mons at {ceph-monitor=192.168.0.173:6789/0,ceph-node01=192.168.0.171:6789/0,ceph-node02=192.168.0.172:6789/0}
        election epoch 28, quorum 0,1,2 ceph-node01,ceph-node02,ceph-monitor
  fsmap e25: 1/1/1 up {0=ceph-monitor=up:active}
 osdmap e55: 3 osds: 3 up, 3 in
        flags sortbitwise
  pgmap v302: 368 pgs, 9 pools, 3704 bytes data, 191 objects
        120 MB used, 15206 MB / 15326 MB avail
             368 active+clean
```

I have set up a separate client node. When I try to mount the filesystem

```
mount -t ceph 192.168.0.173:6789:/ /mnt/cephfs -o name=admin,secret=AQC3QjdXi1e3LBAAFzrYKXKz6oupPGXaKaW1cQ==
```

I get this output (after a long delay):

```
mount: 192.168.0.173:6789:/: can't read superblock
```

All services seem to be running:

```
ps -A | grep ceph
1207 ?        00:00:00 ceph-mon
1208 ?        00:00:00 ceph-mds
1375 ?        00:00:00 ceph-osd
```

Has anybody an idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

The problem disappeared when I upgraded my kernel from 3.13 to 4.4x on Ubuntu Server 14.04.

Install the latest kernel version via `apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial` and reboot your machine.

Another option is to use `ceph-fuse` instead of the kernel driver. It gets installed with `apt-get install ceph-fuse`. `ceph-fuse` was able to mount the filesystem without any issues. Have a look here: http://docs.ceph.com/docs/hammer/cephfs/fuse/

Answer (score 0):

after kernel-client mount failed, you can see kernel log to diagnose this problem, maybe the protocol feature is mismatched.

Answer (score 0):

your kernel version is two low，i have this problem too.

Linux version 3.10.0-862.2.3.el7.x86_64   is OK, you can mount cephfs.
but Linux version 3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64 is not OK.